# Need to write a script that runs two scripts, but needs to stop the first one before the 2nd runs

Tags: bash, centos

This is a CentOS 6.x box, on it I have two things that I need to run one right after the other - a shell script and a .sql script.

I want to write a shell script that calls the first script, lets it run and then terminates it after a certain number of hours, and then calls the .sql script (they can't run simultaneously).

I'm unsure how to do the middle part, that is terminating the first script after a certain time limit, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
script.sh &
sleep 4h && kill $!
script.sql
```

This will wait 4 hours then kill the first script and run the second. It always waits 4 hours, even if the script exits early.

If you want to move on immediately, that's a little trickier.

```
script.sh &
pid=$!
sleep 4h && kill "$pid" 2> /dev/null &
wait "$pid"
```